# Install Xcode 11.3 on macOS Mojave?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, macos-mojave

I'm trying to install Xcode 11.3.1 in Mojave but when going to App Store to install it needs macOS Catalina, although my friend has an Xcode 11.3.1 and he has the same macOS version.

So I download it from `developer.apple.com` but when i want to set up it, it's telling me I don't have free space! but I have 10GB for free.

So my question is I have another Volume if I copy the .xip file then past it in this volume it should work and need any specific installation to handle it? 
and do the job as he was in the main system volume?

Answer (score 2):

Just make more free space on your Mac. This is just an approximation value.

Comment: I just have a 225 SSD Disk so, I'm trying but i can't get more than 15GB free So I install the Xcode on other volumes have 125GB free and it's work well but sometimes i feel my mac slow or something is it related?

Answer (score 0):

10GB is not enough.  You're going to need 24-26GB to install XCode, see [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/112949) and [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/110533). The installer needs room to unpack files, swap space, etc.